# NGINX PHP routing in each first subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I currently have the following NGINX config:

```
server {
    [...]

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /app1 {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app1;
    }

    location @app1 {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app1/index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.app1)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3.sock;
    }

    location /app2 {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app2;
    }

    location @app2 {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app2/index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.app2)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3.sock;


    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

And as you can see I currently enable PHP-Routing manual for the subdirectories **/app1** and **/app2** but my goal is to enable PHP-Routing dynamically for each first level subdirectory, for example

**/foo/bar/baz** should be routed to **/foo/index.php?/bar/baz**

without manually configuring the /foo location in the NGINX config.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}
location @php {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)(/.+)$ $1/index.php?$2? last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.3.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
}
```

The named location will rewrite `/foo/bar/baz` to `/foo/index.php?/bar/baz`. Note that by default, the parameter `/bar/baz` will appear in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` rather than `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` as you had it before.